# Normalization with two potential primary keys

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, dependencies

I have the following `STUDENT` relation in first normal form, where `id` has been identified as the primary key (`email` here is also unique for all tuples):

```
STUDENT(id, email, first_name, last_name)
```

I want to normalize this relation/table such that it is in third normal form (3NF).

The dependencies that I've been able to identify from the above `STUDENT` relation/table are the following

*Full:*

```
{ id } → { email }
```

*Transitive:*

```
{ email } → { first_name, last_name }
```

**Here's the part where I'm confused**. I've identified `email` as a transitive dependency as it can be identified by the primary key (`id`), and the attribute/column `email` itself can identify and determine the `first_name` and `last_name`.

...if I was to continue with this idea, I would eventually get to a 3NF which looks like so:

```
STUDENT(id, email)
STUDENT_INFO(email, first_name, last_name)
```

**However, the `STUDENT` relation/table here seems very redundant**, as all it does is point to another relation/table. Is my normalization process here correct? Or did I get my dependencies wrong? It seems that I will always run into this problem whenever the initial relation/table has two candidate keys which both could either be the primary key (`id` or `email` both could uniquely identify each row).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99042/discussion-between-ypercube-and-shnick).

Comment: "The dependencies that I've been able to identify" When some FDs hold, all the others implied per Armstrong's axioms do too. Where are those? The definition of 3NF refers to *certain* transitive FDs. Quote a definition & show your steps applying it & ask about where you are 1st stuck. PS What does "identified by the primary key" mean? Use technical term & use them correctly per their definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where I went wrong:

The important thing about transitive dependencies are these two key factors:

1. If B depends on A, and C depends on B, then C also depends on A (A → B → C)
2. **B is not (or part of) a candidate key**

In my example, I identified the following as a transitive dependency:

```
{ email } → { first_name, last_name }
```

However, this is not the case, as `email` is a *candidate key*, and so instead, if we use `id` as the primary key, we have a full dependency:

```
{ id } → { email, first_name, last_name }
```

Comment: The generic notion of transitive binary relationship is not what is meant in "transitive FD". Find a definition. Also you are confusing the definition of "transitive FD" with other conditions in certain definitions of 3NF that mention transitive FDs. Also it's not clear how whether a FD is full is relevant here--FDs are either partial or full; being full doesn't imply not being transitive. Also the rest of the reasoning isn't clear.